# Piecewise absolutely continuous functions: norm implication

Tags: integration, continuity, normed-spaces

I have the following doubt:

Consider a sequence of functions $(f_k)$, $k=1,2,\ldots$ which are piecewise absolutely continuous functions $f_k: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}^n$ with a finite number of jump discontinuities (they are also left continuous), and its upper right-hand derivative $\dot{f}_k \in L_2$. It is true the following implication?:

if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \| f_k\|_\infty =0$    then  $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty }\left( \int^b_a \| \dot{f}_k(\tau) \|^2 d\tau \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0$

with

$\| f_k\|_\infty=\max_{\tau\in[a,b]} \| f_k(\tau) \|$

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I do not known how to start. I am not a mathematician and I do not have experience with this.

Comment: Try to think of them as function first ($n=1$). Then ask the following question: if $|f(x)|$ is small, does that imply $|f'(x)|$ is also small? (just consider smooth functions)

Comment: Thank your for the counter-example $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}cos(nx)$